# UItableView with UITextfield to NSMutableArray CRASH on Record updates click

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, nsmutablearray, uitextfield

I have UITableView with customcell where UITextField is places, I'm assigning the following action to my UITeextfield to record data to nsmutablearray

```
[textFieldCell.textfield addTarget:self action:@selector(textChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

and the function

```
- (void)textChanged:(UITextField *)source
{
    NSString *str= source.text;
    NSUInteger itager = (([self.tableView indexPathForCell:(TextFieldCell *)[[source superview] superview]].row)-1);
    [collectedAnswersArray replaceObjectAtIndex:itager withObject:str];
    NSLog(@"replacing at %i = %@",itager,[collectedAnswersArray objectAtIndex:itager]);

}
```

At the end of the table I have my last cell as insert the record once it clicked I'm recording data to database from mutable array.

The problem I'm facing that application crashes if my focus still on the textfield and for some strange reason it throughs the exception back to this line:
[collectedAnswersArray replaceObjectAtIndex:itager withObject:str];
saying that 489045358493 beyond the range.But it's not about the range. 
If I'm dismissing keyboard everything is fine.

Jow to loose focus from the textfield which are not anymore visible in my textfield. Because I have a feeling that it keeps some reference to that textfield or smth and that's what causes it.

Comment: I found the issue , it was just me not paying attention enough to the itager variable...

Answer (score 0):

Just Try this:
[collectedAnswersArray replaceObjectAtIndex:[itager intValue] withObject:str];